# Regularity theorem for Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$ be a bounded domain, $d>2$. Let $f \in C^\infty(\Omega)$. If $u \in L^2$ is a distributional solution of $\Delta u = f$ in $\Omega$ then $u \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ and it is a classical solution. This can be easily proved: we can explicitly specify one of the solutions of $\Delta u = f$ of class $С^\infty$, it is $u' = K*f$, where $K$ is the Newton kernel. Next we can easily show that any solution of $\Delta u = 0$ is $C^\infty$ from what we can derive that $u = u' + (u-u') \in C^\infty$. More precisely this procedure is described in [these](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.mcgill.ca%2Fgantumur%2Fmath580f11%2Fdownloads%2FPoisson.pdf&ei=ahOeUsCqBMXV0QXxu4HoDg&usg=AFQjCNHHes3-jzOQA76Cx4mSlVV-pDcMAQ&sig2=AESpAg3tlNFr-eh_A1wF1A&bvm=bv.57155469,d.Yms&cad=rja) lecture notes, p.8, thm. 2.

The situation is more complicated in the case when $f \in H^k$, where $H^k$ is the Sobolev space, $k \geq 0$. In this case I expect to show that if $u$ is a distributional solution of $\Delta u = f$ then $u \in H^{k+2}$ and $\Delta u = f$ a.e. As above we represent $u = u'+(u-u')$ where $u'$ is some particular distributional solution of $\Delta u = f$. The problem is to show that we can specify such particular solution in the class $H^{k+2}$. Formally we can take convolution of distributions $K*f$, but I'm not sure that $K*f \in H^{k+2}$ since $K$ is not in $L^2$ for $d \geq 4$. Is there a way to generalize the above approach to prove regularity in this Sobolev case?

P.S. I know about other ways to prove regularity, e.g. [Bers, Schechter], but I'm interested if the approach for $C^\infty$ functions is easily extendable.

Comment: A little side-note question. Is there a relation between weak solutions and distributional solutions? Because, at least in weak sense, if we want $u|_{\partial \Omega}=0$ and if $f\in H^0$, then we have a unique solution in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, not in $H^2$.

Comment: You might want to check out good old Rudin: *Functional Analysis* – the section on elliptic equations in Chapter 8.  It follows from Theorem 8.12 that you get a solution that is locally in $H^{s+2}$ if the right hand side is locally in $H^2$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Do you mean the relation in the case $f \in L^2$? I don't know. But I wasn't speaking about boundary values

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen it seems that we need to prove a huge number of auxilary results to use the theorem 8.12

Comment: Indeed. In fact, when I took a class in functional analysis based on Rudin's book back in the stone ages, this result was the crowning jewel to the whole course. Where everything we had learned came together to prove this classical result.

Comment: I know that here we don't have boundary values, nevertheless, it was worth mentioning that in that case we only get a `+1` in global regularity, not `+2`. And, of course $L^2=H^0$ by definition of spaces $H^s$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen by the way in my question the operator is the Laplacian and not a general elliptic operator, this gives me hope that one can prove the result much easier